# Self signed SSL client certificate not received by server

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, self-signed, ca

I am trying to implement two way ssl authentication in asp.net mvc 4 web api project. I'm following the blog posted at http://woloski.com/2012/08/04/securing-aspnet-webapi-with-clientcerts/ but cannot get to work with selfsigned client certificate.

I have implemented the message handler, created self signed certificates, and imported the CA certificate to Trusted root as suggested in the reference article.

But on the server side `request.GetClientCertificate()` is always `null`, while I can see the certificate being added to `ClientCertificates` collection of Request.

I have tried with real certificate that I received from startcom, and that certificate works fine.

Could anyone help, why my self signed certificate isn't working?

Comment: You probably need to trust your own certificate on the server as well as the client.

Comment: @Davio I'm currently testing on same machine. So, both client and server is the same. Also, I'm using IIS express, so is there some setting that I need to modify in IIS express?